# Installing PEAR on Windows 7

Tags: php, pear

Ok guys, I've been trying to do this for 3 days. I downloaded php5 and tried unsuscessfully to install pear, it installed but would just give me a return on the cli when i tried to install a package. 
So I deleted the php5 folder and all the enviornemnt variables.
I put in a php7 folder and tried downloading the go-pear.phar file using curl, and updated the enviornment variables. Now when I run the "php go-pear.phar" command it gets stuck in an infinite loop and I have to press cntrl-c to exit. it says ***ERROR*** where you should press enter. 
I don't know if the previous version of php is throwing off the install, is there anything besides the enviornment variables? A bin directory?? Should I just get a mac and blow this laptop?

Comment: Show errors, please.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to do a manual install. If anyone does this and gets an error that the pear install dir is wrong, just search the bat file for "pear" and you'll see where they added it to the %prefix%
https://nikic.github.io/2011/12/03/Manually-installing-PEAR-on-Windows.html
that was a bitch!